# Allow admin login at /admin

Tags: admin, urls, htaccess

I am interested in:

1. how can we change the default login url `/wp-admin` to `/login`
2. how can we add another url for login so that both `/wp-admin` and `/login` would work

I tried to use a custom filter and .htaccess as in the following example but without success.

functions.php

```
add_filter('admin_url', 'my_new_admin_url');

function my_new_admin_url()
{
    return '/login/';
}
```

.htaccess

```
Redirect permanent /wp-admin/ /login/
```

Comment: I've never seen that `admin_url` filter usage, do you have a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another option - redirect `/admin/` to `wp-login.php` with a `parse_query` action hook:

```
function wpa53048_parse_query( $query ){
    if( $query->query_vars['pagename'] == 'admin' ):
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        exit;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpa53048_parse_query' );
```

**EDIT**

Well the above apparently only works with certain permalink structures. Here's another method hooked to `parse_request`:

```
function wpa53048_parse_request( $query ){
    if( $query->request == 'admin' ):
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        exit;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa53048_parse_request' );
```

Comment: I understand what you mean and I find this to be a good way of dealing with this redirect but unfortunately it doesn't work. Any ideas if this has any compatibility issues with WP 3.3.2 ?

Thanks

Comment: @thedev - my first method seems to depend on the permalink structure, it works if you use date-based permalinks but not postname or a static prefix. i added another, similar method.

Comment: Second solution works great, except one case. When I use the default permalinks with ?p=  I receive a 404 error. Any ideea why this is happening ?

Comment: @thedev - With default permalinks you'll get your server's 404 page, since requests for anything not a physical file or directory are no longer being routed through WordPress. In that case you will have to use brasofilo's technique with an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

I use just this at the top of my .htaccess file:
`RewriteRule ^login/?$ /wp-login.php [NC,L]`

or the following, case WordPress resides in a folder, and the rule refers to the root:
`RewriteRule ^login/?$ /wp/wp-login.php [NC,L]`

I've seen [QSA,L] used instead of [NC,L], but don't know the difference...

*Reference: http://planetozh.com/blog/2011/01/pretty-login-url-a-simple-rewrite-api-plugin-example/*